# How to update specific entry in SQL database

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

```
Private Sub cmdRRupdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdRRupdate.Click
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim o As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        o = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex

        cn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "update RepairRenovation Set Project_ID = '" & txtRRprojectID.Text & "', Date = '" & rrIdate.Value & "', Source_of_Fund = '" & txtRRsof.Text & "', Contractor = '" & txtRRcontractor.Text & "', Scope_of_Works = '" & txtRRsow.Text & "' where convert (varchar, ID_Number) = '" & DataGridView4.Item(0, i).Value & "'"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        txtRRprojectID.Text = ""
        txtRRsof.Text = ""
        txtRRcontractor.Text = ""
        txtRRsof.Text = ""
        txtRRsow.Text = ""
        ref3()
    End Sub
```

I used `where convert (varchar, Project_ID)` but whenever I update one entry, it updates the entry of all who have the same `Project_ID`. So, I used `ID_Number` as `Primary Key` to update the specific entry. But whenever I try to update it, the entry doesn't change/update.

Comment: Id ID_Number integer in your database?

Comment: You *really* should switch to parameterizing your queries. You are opening yourself up to SQL Injection.

Comment: @Whencesoever yes, it is integer in database.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "update RepairRenovation Set Project_ID = '" & txtRRprojectID.Text & "', Date = '" & rrIdate.Value & "', Source_of_Fund = '" & txtRRsof.Text & "', Contractor = '" & txtRRcontractor.Text & "', Scope_of_Works = '" & txtRRsow.Text & "' where ID_Number = " & DataGridView4.Item(0, i).Value
```

Did You debug Your code? Have You looked at what is inside that string that is command text?

Comment: It says "Invalid column name 'RW'." RW is the Project_ID which was inputted by the user

Comment: so how is it integer in your database when user puts a text there not integer?

Comment: The Project_ID is set to text. ID_Number is set to INT, IDENTITY, PRIMARY KEY

Comment: So You say that it is project ID, and u make query with where for ID_NUMBER. There is a mistake here. When You do this string with update.